# Joint measurability of metric.

Tags: integration, general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Consider the following excerpt from ["Distance covariance in metric spaces" by Ryssell Lyons](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.5758):

[image]
Both in the Lemma and in order to define $D(\mu)$ one needs that  $d:X\times X \to [0,\infty]$ is $ \mathcal{B}(X) \otimes \mathcal{B}(X)  /\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ measurable, but in the proof of the lemma this is omitted.

In the "Handbook of Analysis and its Foundations" by Eric Schechter, one finds the following corrollary to Nedoma's Pathology
[image]

From this we can deduce, that the Russell Lyons article is erroneous in that the described setup (with $X$ being a general metric space) allows for integrals that are not well-defined.

We know that if $X$ is separable then $d$ is jointly measurable, but is there a (easily comprehensible) property of metric spaces, which is equivalent to saying that the metric $d$ is $\mathcal{B}(X) \otimes \mathcal{B}(X)$-measurable?